# Удаление внешнего и главного ключа

Tags: mysql

Почему происходит ошибка, если я удаляю с начала внешний ключ из дочерней, а потом - primary из родительской таблицы?

```
ALTER TABLE `docher` DROP FOREIGN KEY `id`;
ALTER TABLE rodit DROP primary key;
```

Comment: Вероятнее всего из-за того, что есть еще связи.

Comment: А не могли бы Вы добавить в вопрос вывод команд show create table rodit и show create table docher?

Comment: И еще текст ошибки не помешал бы

Comment: А если наоборот - то всё хорошо?

Comment: нет . .  .

Comment: @Ksenia секретных данных о таблицах, запросах и ошибках мы, видимо, не дождёмся.

Answer (score 1):

Внешний ключ обычно можно удалять только если он не используется, т.е. если нету записей на которые он ссылается. Если вы хотите прибить ключ, без потери данных, то вам надо для начала сдублировать колонку, потом перенести данные из ключевой колонки в него, потом обнулить ключи, а потом уже прибивать внешний ключ. Как то так.